# @Valid Not working @PostMapping spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I am learning spring boot, I am adding Validation for @PostMapping, but somehow it always create a object even with non-valid value.

Hospital.java

```
public class Hospital {
    private Integer id;
    @Size(min = 2)
    private String name;
    @Size(min = 2)
    private String city;

    public Hospital(Integer id, String name, String city) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
    }
```

Controller

```
@Autowired
    HospitalData data;
...
@PostMapping("/hospital")
    public ResponseEntity<Hospital> addHospital(@Valid @RequestBody Hospital hospital){
        Hospital newHospital = data.addHospital(hospital);

        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
        .fromCurrentRequest()
        .path("/{id}")
        .buildAndExpand(newHospital.getId()).toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

And previously I have added below dependency as I am using Spring 2.3.10 RELEASE, but it doesn't work, so I have added above dependency.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: With the spring-boot-starter-validation, like described at this post: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation I see no reason for this to not work.

Comment: give us some concrete examples of what non valid values have passed without failing

Comment: `@Size(min = 2)` does not mean it can not be null. In that case you also want another annotation `@NotNull `

Comment: @Boug : I have added @NotNull and @Size(min=2), and when I am passing ```{
"name": "b",
"city": "A" 
}``` it still got 201 created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a Test Application reproducing the state of your code. As stated under the comments, the code you provided should definitely work. You definitely **don't** neet to provide a `BindingResult` to the method. Spring Boot throws a [MethodArgumentNotValidException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/MethodArgumentNotValidException.html) and therefore returns a bad request http status if the validation fails.

I created a project with following content:

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

DemoEntity:

```
public class DemoEntity {
    @NotNull
    public String name;
    @Size(min = 3)
    public String greeting;
}
```

DemoController:

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {
    @PostMapping("/post")
    public ResponseEntity<DemoEntity> put(@Valid @RequestBody DemoEntity demoEntity) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(demoEntity);
    }
}
```

Now, that's what happens with my requests:

| Name | Greeting | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | Mr | 400 |
| Stephen | Monsieur | 200 |
| Clara | null | 200 |
| Jenny | Madamme | 200 |

As you see from the table above, when `greeting` is `null` the result is an ok status. If you want to guarantee that the string is at least `min` characters long *and* not null, you need to declare this explicitely.

That's, for example, if you want to validate optional fields like a mobile number. You know, it should be n numbers long and contain only numbers, but you don't want to make it mandatory. Like I showed with the greeting above.

Comment: Thanks, I had some weird experience, I removed the json body that I passed in postman and I typed again the same json body and now I am getting proper validation response and proper HTTPStatus.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the BindingResult object as the param immediately following your form object and then manually check if there were any errors.

See https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/ Create a Web Controller for a good example of how this should be done in your controller.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's wrong. As I demonstrated in my answer, the code OP provided works. I assume the requests contained null values.

Comment: Probably, however a post controller receiving a form post still needs to use the BindingResult object anyway so it can intelligently forward to the correct page to display errors and ask for corrected input.

Comment: It depends on several aspects. If OP is just providing an api for data which should be validates, he doesn't nee dto provide user information. Yes, it would be good (and he can implement this in a exception handler, like I have linked), but not necessary. Especially if hes using that entity in multiple requests.